# SQL compare data pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve this problem but I cant get very far.

The question is:

> **"find pairs of names (renamed as name1 and name2) where each name1 acts in the same film as name2 but has earned more pay for acting in said film."**

The table for Acted In is:

```
ActedIn (name:varchar, title:varchar, year:int, pay:real)
```

My query so far is:

```
SELECT B.name FROM ActedIn B WHERE B.title IN (
SELECT A.title FROM ActedIn A GROUP BY A.title HAVING COUNT(*) = 2);
```

This returns: (without the title and pay columns, which is fine - I just included it so you can see)

```
+---------------+--------------+
| name | title  |  EXAMPLE PAY |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Dino | movie1 | 500.25       |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Miro | movie1 | 40.15        |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Tino | movie2 | 90.15        |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Kiko | movie2 | 3422.24      |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Bino | movie3 | 653.00       |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Kiko | movie3 | 245.52       |
+------+--------+--------------+
```

Now I need to somehow compare the pairs of actors in each movie title and return only the pairs where actor1 has a greater pay than actor2.

In the case I provided above, the result of said query should be:

```
 Dino, Miro in Movie1
 Bino, Kiko in Movie3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select x.name as name1, y.name as name2, x.title as movie
from actedin x join actedin y on x.title = y.title
where x.example_pay > y.example_pay
```

Comment: Changed to use the join keyword